# Breakout Game (C#) - Bat Collision Issue

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013

I am currently creating a Breakout game in C# and I am having a problem with my bat collision. When I go to hit the ball with the bat, the ball is getting caught on the bat and isn't being hit correctly. Quite hard to explain, but I was wondering if anyone could spot a problem in my code that might be causing this.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BreakOut_Game
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics paper;
        Pen pen;
        Rectangle ball, bat, brick1, brick2, brick3, brick4, brick5, brick6, brick7, brick8, brick9, brick10;
        Random randomNumber;
        private int ballX, ballY, batX, batY, xChange, yChange;
        public int lives;
        public int score;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            paper = picMainGame.CreateGraphics();

            pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            pen.Width = 2;


            picMainGame.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(picDraw_MouseMove);

            randomNumber = new Random();
            score = 0;

            lblLives.Text = ("Lives: " + lives);
            lblScore.Text = ("Score: " + score);

        }
        private void picDraw_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                batX = e.X;
                batY = e.Y;
            }
        }

        private void drawBat()
        {

            bat = new Rectangle(batX + 10, picMainGame.Height - 30, 40, 12);
            paper.DrawRectangle(pen, bat);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, bat);
        }



        public void drawBall()
        {
            pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            ball = new Rectangle(ballX, ballY, 8, 8);
            paper.DrawEllipse(pen, ball);
            paper.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, ball);
        }

        public void moveBall()
        {

            ballX = ballX + xChange;
            ballY = ballY + yChange;

            if ((ballX >= picMainGame.Width) || (ballX <= 0))
                xChange = -xChange;

            if (ballY <= 0)
                yChange = -yChange;

            if ((ballX >= (batX - 25)) && (ballX <= (batX + 25)) && (ballY >= (picMainGame.Height - 30)))

            if (ballY >= picMainGame.Height)
      {
          lives = lives - 1;
          lblLives.Text = Convert.ToString(lives);
          timer1.Enabled = false;

          btnLaunch.Enabled = true;

      }
 }

        public void createBricks()
        {
            brick1 = new Rectangle(25, 3, 50, 10);
            brick2 = new Rectangle(76, 3, 50, 10);
            brick3 = new Rectangle(127, 3, 50, 10);
            brick4 = new Rectangle(178, 3, 50, 10);
            brick5 = new Rectangle(229, 3, 50, 10);
            brick6 = new Rectangle(280, 3, 50, 10);
            brick7 = new Rectangle(331, 3, 50, 10);
            brick8 = new Rectangle(382, 3, 50, 10);
            brick9 = new Rectangle(433, 3, 50, 10);
            brick10 = new Rectangle(484, 3, 50, 10);

        }

        public void drawBricks()
        {
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, brick1);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, brick1);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, brick2);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, brick2);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, brick3);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, brick3);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, brick4);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, brick4);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, brick5);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, brick5);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Yellow, brick6);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, brick6);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, brick7);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, brick7);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, brick8);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, brick8);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, brick9);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, brick9);
            paper.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, brick10);
            paper.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, brick10);

        }

        private void checkBatCollision()
        {
            if (ball.IntersectsWith(bat))
            {
                xChange = -xChange;
                yChange = -yChange;
            }
        }


      public void checkCollision()
    {

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick1))
        {
            brick1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick2))
        {
            brick2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick3))
        {
            brick3 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick4))
        {
            brick4 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick5))
        {
            brick5 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick6))
        {
            brick6 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick7))
        {
            brick7 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick8))
        {
            brick8 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick9))
        {
            brick9 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick10))
        {
            brick10 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
            score = score + 10;
            yChange = -yChange;     
        }


       }


        private void picMainGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCredit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lives == 0)
            {
                lives = lives + 5;
                lblLives.Text = Convert.ToString(lives);

                btnCredit.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void btnDisplayBricks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lives == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insert Credit to play!");
            }
            else
            {

                createBricks();
                drawBricks();
                btnLaunch.Enabled = true;

            }
        }

        private void btnLaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ballX = 100;
            ballY = 150;

            xChange = -7;
            yChange = -7;


            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timer1.Enabled == false)
                timer1.Enabled = true;

            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;

            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            paper.Clear(Color.Silver);
            drawBat();
            drawBall();
            drawBricks();
            moveBall();
            checkBatCollision();
            checkCollision();
            btnLaunch.Enabled = false;
            btnPause.Enabled = true;
            btnDisplayBricks.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void picMainGame_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can remove most of your code if you create an Array of Bricks using a `Rectangle[]` and use `foreach` loops where you have copied your code per brick.

Comment: `CreateGraphics` is almost always the wrong way to draw/paint something

Answer (score 0):

So many things.

Wouldn't it be easier to represent the ball and bricks in memory and then draw the representation of its state at intervals?

With your current implementation you could also I improve performance by keeping the sprites (balls) as seperate images and just moving them where required.

Drawing everything on a single plain only helps if number of sprites / balls are very large.

There are various other problems which also attribute to your error such as the size of the element vs its size on screen hence where the representation helps to achieve resolution scaling.

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Hi Jay. Thanks for your quick response. I have only just started programming which is why there are quite a lot of things wrong with my code. However, is there any way I can quickly fix this problem as I am on a tight deadline? I just need the basic functionality of this program to work. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How quickly you can fix it is up to you. I would start by determining where you afford to change things to fit both your underlying understanding as well as your dead line.